# Getting function PTR from DLL

Tags: c#, c++, dll

I'm trying to inject a dll into my current process to find the offsets to the different functions.

I have a simple function inside my dll which looks like this:

```
void testfunction()
```

And im trying to get the function ptr through an C# app.

```
    public IntPtr GetFunctionPointer()
    {
        IntPtr hLoaded = LoadLibrary("C:\\test\\test.dll");
        IntPtr functionPtr = GetProcAddress(hLoaded, "testfunction");


        return functionPtr;
    }
```

The function ptr returns 0 everytime even though the function exists inside of the dll.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you mean __declspec(dllexport) void testfunction()?

Comment: Well, that does export the function, with a mangled name.  Use `dumpbin /exports` on your DLL to see the actual names.  To have control of the exported name (prevent mangling) you'd need to use a module definition file.

Comment: Note libraries like [EasyHook](http://easyhook.codeplex.com/) will help out a lot in stuff like this, it has functions to get the address while trying out the mangled forms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function isn't named `testfunction` in your DLL's export table, it has been mangled with type information.  So `GetProcAddress` won't find it.  (P/invoke `DllImportAttribute` tried a whole slew of names, which may find it... or not.  But `GetProcAddress` requires exact match.)

In order to export a function with no mangling at all, you need to reduce mangling of the function name using `extern "C"`, and then also link using a module definition file.  Something like:

```
LIBRARY test
EXPORTS
testfunction
```

For complete information, see [the MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/28d6s79h.aspx)